# Symfony2 remove default Form fields style class

Tags: css, forms, symfony

When rendering a form field It adds a class that messes up my styling.. All I want to do is remove the class when rendereing the field, but how can I do that? I know that you can set up classes for fields, but I need to remove a default class.

I render like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword }}
```

The only way I can do this now, is go to the vendor `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout` file and remove the line:

```
{% block form_group_class -%}
    col-sm-10 ///remove this
{%- endblock form_group_class %}
```

However that is not the solution, because you cant manually edit vendor files.. What are my options? How to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check [the documentation about form theme "Application-wide Customizations"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations).

You can create a form theme template which extends `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout` and override `form_group_class` block like this:

```
{% use 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_group_class %}{% endblock form_group_class %}
```

and then set this template as a global form theme in you `config.yml` (assuming it is located in your `MyAppBundle` in `form/my_form_theme.html.twig`):

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'MyAppBundle:form:my_form_theme.html.twig'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either define your [own theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) for a form type or add the html manually and use the [raw form variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#twig-reference-form-variables)